# Producing view when indexing numpy array with range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I noticed that, in contrast to `slice`, using `range` to index an array does not produce a view of the numpy array.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3, 3))

s = slice(1, 3)
b = a[1, s]
b[:] = 1
print(a)
# [[0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]]

r = range(1, 3)
b = a[1, r]
b[:] = 1
print(a)
# [[0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Are there quick/elegant ways to convert a `range` to a `slice` other than using `.start, .stop, .step` manually?

```py
def range2slice(r):
    return slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
```

Or is there a way that I get numpy to yield the view even if I use `range` to index the array?

Basically I want an object which I can iterate over AND which produces a view when used as index.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would find quicker or more "elegant" than `slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)`. A `range` is a sequence, so NumPy behaves as with any other sequence. They _could_ treat it specially, although it is not exactly like a slice: `np.arange(4)[slice(2, 5)]` works, but `np.arange(4)[range(2, 5)]` fails.

Comment: While `range` has attributes like `slice`, `numpy` expands to a list, as in `np.array(range(3))`.  I suspect it's a carry over from Py2 where `range(3)` actually produced a list.  It doesn't expand other generators.  I agree that making a `slice` object from the `range` attributes is the quick/elegant way.